# What can go wrong if a check valve in a shower mixer is missing?

Tags: plumbing

I have a Grohe pressure balanced shower mixer (cartridge is model 47157000) and the check valve (model 47158000) on the cold side isn’t working.

When the check valve is installed, hardly any water comes out. When removed, the shower is great.

Knowing that the hot water is supplied by *(edit)* a **dedicated** on-demand water heater, what is the downside of removing the check valve?

My primitive notion is that the pressure on the hot side is roughly equal to the pressure on the cold side, so it *seems* like there shouldn’t be a problem. But I’m the first to say that I’m not a plumber, so that’s why I’m here.

Comment: Would do a test with your favourite SO.  Have them use the shower and you turn on hot water full some place else.  No screams you are good.

Comment: Your edit takes all the fun out of it.  Hot water usually is at higher pressure than cold, not much but some.  One reason why there are pressure relieve valves on hot water tanks but not on cold water pipes.

Comment: Do you have a manual for the valve? My guess, it's either defective or installed incorrectly so it's cutting off the cold water because it thinks that's the right thing to do.

Comment: @crip659 - *"Hot water usually is at higher pressure than cold"* under what circumstances? Mine certainly isn't. Both come directly from the water main, but the hot gets restricted through the heater.

Comment: @Tetsujin  Heating water will raise it's pressure, might just be a few pounds more than the cold water pressure.  Some people place check valves on the cold water line at the tank to prevent the hot water from going into the cold water line.

Comment: Neither of the above, here. The hot is way lower pressure & flow than the cold, once it's been through the heater.

Comment: I once worked in an institutional scullery for used dishes from a refectory. In that place the hot water supply was at higher pressure than the cold. There was a certin sink with a mixing valve through which the hot water would displace the water in the cold water supply line. With the hot valve off, hot water would comeout of the cold line. In standard residental plumbing with a hot water tank the cold is at the same pressure as the hot water (static or flow). With a tankless WH under flow the hot water is at considerablly lower pressure than the cold due to pressure drop in the tankless WD.

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure:

I do not have pressure balanced shower mixer with check valve nor the dedicated on-demand water heater.

So the risk of water pressure change is much higher then your set up. Still rarely I have to    if someone wants to harm me by opening high water consumption cold or hot.